# Nested if formula with % range

Tags: excel

90% +   Ist Division
71% - 90 %  IInd Division
40% - 70%   IIIrd Division
< 40%   Fail

Nested if excel formula for excel for above condition .

I applied below formula but seems to be not correct:

=IF(AND(i4>=40%,i4<=70%),"3rd",IF(AND(i4>=71%,i4<=90%),"2nd",IF(i4>90%,"ist"),IF(i4<40%,"fail")))

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be?  Can you provide examples, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Start at the top:

```
=IF(I4>.9,"1st",IF(I4>=.71,"2nd",IF(I4>=.4,"3rd","FAIL")))
```

This way one only needs to step through the lowest threshold.  Once one of the Ifs returns true it will not do the others.